# How do I multiply for my e-commerce project with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I make an e-trade site with reactjs for my personal education. I'm Beginner ***When I press the add button on the products, I want it to multiply its price by the middle number***. Data comes from json file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkYW4.png

```
const vegetables = require('./vegetables');
return (
    vegetables.items.map((item,index)=>{
      return (
        <div class="meyve-div">
          <div class="" style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
          <Card className="" style={{ width:'250px', filter: 'grayscale(100%)' }}>
            <Card.Img className="cardImage" variant="top" src={item.image} style={{ width: '200px',marginLeft:'30px'}}/>  
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>{item.name} - 1 KG 
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Text  style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
              {item.value}
              </Card.Text>
              <div className="ToplamaKısmı" style={{ textAlign: 'center' , display:' inline-flex'}}>
                <Button style={{marginRight: '30px'}} onClick={()=>item.counter && this.decrement(index)}>-</Button>
                  <h2 value="1">{item.counter}</h2>
                <Button style={{marginLeft: '30px'}} onClick={()=>this.increment(index)}>+</Button>
              </div>
              <div className="butondiv">
              <Button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style={{backgroundColor:'#2dc44d',borderColor:'#2dc44d'}}>
              Add to Card
            </Button>
              </div>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }):null    )}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use state for this.

```
const vegetables = require('./vegetables');

const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

return (
  vegetables.items.map((item,index)=>{
  setCount(item.counter)
  return (
    <div class="meyve-div">
      <div class="" style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
      <Card className="" style={{ width:'250px', filter: 'grayscale(100%)' }}>
        <Card.Img className="cardImage" variant="top" src={item.image} style={{ width: '200px',marginLeft:'30px'}}/>  
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>{item.name} - 1 KG 
          </Card.Title>
          <Card.Text  style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
          {count * item.value}
          </Card.Text>
          <div className="ToplamaKısmı" style={{ textAlign: 'center' , display:' inline-flex'}}>
            <Button style={{marginRight: '30px'}} onClick={()=> setCount(count--)}>-</Button>
              <h2 value="1">{count}</h2>
            <Button style={{marginLeft: '30px'}} onClick={()=> setCount(count++)}>+</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="butondiv">
          <Button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style={{backgroundColor:'#2dc44d',borderColor:'#2dc44d'}}>
          Add to Card
        </Button>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

}):null    )}}

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit unclear but you may want to do something like this:

```
onIncrement = (index) => {
   let updatedVegetables = [...vegetables]
   let vegetable = updatedVegetables[index]
   vegetable = {
      ...vegetable, 
      value: vegetable.value * vegetable.counter
   }
   updatedVegetables[index] = {...vegetable}
}
```

Now you can updated your state with this updatedVegetables.